# Google compute disk encryption with KMS key using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

What is the Terraform syntax to encrypt the `google_compute_disk` using a custom managed KMS key in the Google cloud platform?

Referring the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_disk.html) and using the KMS key `self_link` for `disk_encryption_key.raw_key` seems to not work. The resulting disk generated shows the disk is encrypted via Google managed key.

Am using a wrong format?

Sample being used is given below:

```
**resource "google_compute_disk" "ext_disk" {
  name  = "testdisk"
  type  = "pd-ssd"
  zone = "${var.zone}"
  size = 16
  labels {
    environment = "${var.target_environment}"   
  }
  disk_encryption_key {
    raw_key = "${google_kms_crypto_key.crypto_key.self_link}"
  }
}**
```

Answer (score 0):

KMS key is not really supported via Terraform to encrypt disk .This is currently tagged to enhancement with GCP's Terraform team .I was facing the same issue some time back and raised the query with them .Here is ticket number -https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/2234 .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the GCP provider with versions < 2.0.0 then there isn't a great solution. You are providing the `self_link` but the `compute_disk` resource needs a raw key, which [cannot be exported](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/faq#export_keys) or imported.

If you are using 2.0.0 or later then a new field `kms_key_self_link` will be available to be used to refer to the KMS key resource.